# Mercurial 2.1.1 - Determine if a changeset is a merge

Tags: mercurial, merge, hg-log

In Mercurial `2.4` a template keyword `{p2rev}` was added that can be used to determine if a changeset is a merge.

```
hg log -r42 --template {p2rev}
```

If this returns "-1", there is no second parent, hence the changeset is *not* a merge, otherwise it *is* a merge.

But most devs here still are on Mercurial `2.1.1`.  Using `{p2rev}` on their machines always returns [blank].

I tried in 2.1.1:

```
hg log -r42 --template {parents}
```

and this gives a bit *weird* output:

- if there is only 1 parent (not a merge): no output
- if there are 2 parents (merge): the {rev}:{node} of **both** parents

**What is the best way to determine if a changeset is a merge in Mercurial *pre-2.4*, say `2.1.1` ?**

Comment: I believe that a single parent can be reported, but only if the one parent is *not* the previous change-set. If it's the previous change-set, then it's omitted.

Answer (score 1):

The [`hg parents`](http://selenic.com/hg/help/parents) command might do what you want:

```
hg parents -r 42 --template "{node|short}\n"
```

For a merge changeset you will get 2 lines of output, and for a non-merge changeset you'll get 1 line.

Comment: That is equivalent to `hg log -r42 --template {parents}` in the question. Definitely usable, but still feels a bit _weird_

Comment: Are you sure? I thought you said your version gave *no* output for non-merge changesets, whereas mine will return one line.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mercurial 2.2.2 (Ubuntu 12.10) and it seems that this is working (using the *Revision Sets* query language):

```
$ hg log -r 'merge()'
changeset:   6:f75b34694a73
parent:      4:129b7b24f6b4
parent:      5:85771af34f42
[...]
summary:     Merge branch 'default' of /foo/proto

changeset:   12:04975792d1f3
parent:      10:42c64107845f
parent:      11:226623b54bd2
[...]
summary:     merged branch 'experimental-bar' into 'default'
```

Comment: This selects changesets that are merges.  In my case, I already have a changeset, 42, that I would like to test for being a merge. This helped me towards my answer though.

Answer (score 0):

If

```
hg log -r"42 & merge()" --template x
```

returns a non-empty string, Then changeset 42 is a merge.
The template returns the letter x if there is a result.